# Workbooks.Add doesn't activate the new workbook when running from Workbook_Open()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro when my workbook is opened. The macro is supposed to create a new workbook using `Workbooks.Add` and end with the new workbook active. However, I cannot seem to make this happen no matter what I try.

The simplest attempts I tried were the following (you can try it yourself):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

Or this one from within the module itself:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

I tried various things such as adding the following lines of code:

`DoEvents` or

`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))`

I also tried using `If Then` statements to check the name of the active workbook, but that didn't work either.

In the end, the original file that I clicked on is still the active workbook. How can I get the newly created workbook to be the active window when the macro is finished running? Thanks!

Edit: By the way, note that if you try running the exact same code in a regular sub, it behaves the way that I want. It just doesn't seem to work when running in the 'run on workbook open' subs.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, the first code snippet worked fine.

Comment: Yep... it works fine. Maybe try restarting the Excel after closing from Task Manager.

Comment: I just closed Excel completely and opened the "test_file.xlsm" workbook. What I end up seeing is "test_file" active with "Book1" behind it. Is this not what you are seeing? I'm on Office 365. @dwirony

Comment: @Mikku See my reply to dwirony above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Wait` just idles the Excel Application, so that won't work as you've observed. If all else fails (I'm not in a position to test at the moment) you could use `Application.OnTime` to schedule a procedure that creates a new workbook and activates it, 1 second *after* the `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "addNewWb"
End Sub

Private Sub addNewWb()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think to try that myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running all the different ways I can. But a workaround is to add a `MsgBox`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        wb.Activate

        MsgBox "New Book Added"

End Sub
```

When you will click okay on the MsgBox, it will stay on the Newly created Workbook.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work as you said. However, for my purposes, I can't rely on the user to click on the box. Good to know that Msgbox can do that though!